Given S.P.D. matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, solve $X^\top A X=\mathbf{I}_{m\times m}$ for matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
Context:
Given a symmitric positive definite (SPD) matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, solve the following for matrix $\mathbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$.
$$
\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{I}_{m\times m}\;,
$$
where $\mathbf{I}_{m\times m}$ is a $m\times m$ identity matrix.
My Attempt:
For $m \leq n$, the problem will have the solutions $\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{A}^{-1/2} \mathbf{Q}$ for a unique (SPD) $\mathbf{A}^{-1/2}$ and some semi-orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{Q}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ such that $\mathbf{Q}^\top \mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{I}_{m\times m}$.
My Question:
Can we say something about the case for when $m > n$? I am not sure how to go about it since that problem seems underdetermined to me (I think?).
Also, is my solution for $m\leq n$ fine or am I missing something?
Thanks!

if $m\gt n$ then what is the maximal rank of the left hand side?

@user8675309 I think since $\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}) = \min\left(\text{rank}(\mathbf{A}), \text{rank}(\mathbf{B})\right)$, and $m > n$, therefore $\text{rank}(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}) \leq n$ since $\mathbf{A}$ has rank of $n$.

conclude $m =\text{rank}(\mathbf I_m)= \text{rank}(\mathbf{X}^\top\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X}) \leq n \lt m$ which is impossible

Your solution for $m \leq n$ is correct. Note that $X^TAX = I$ implies that $A^{1/2}X$ is semi-orthogonal.

there is a simple algorithm for starting with real symmetric $A$  and constructing a nonsingular  square  $P$  such that $P^T A P = D$  is diagonal. If the elements of $A$ are rational so are the elements of $P$ and $D.$  Finally, for $A$ definite, so is $D.$  A final step with a diagonal matrix $M$  with some square roots gives $M^T DM = I,$  where actually $M^T = M$   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
